# Why does the documentation use the word "directly" while defining "scope"?

Tags: python, scope, reference, namespaces

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces):

> A scope is a textual region of a Python program where a namespace is directly accessible. “Directly accessible” here means that an unqualified reference to a name attempts to find the name in the namespace.

Why does the documentation use the word "directly" while defining "scope"? Has it got some significance? Will it make a difference if "scope" is defined as *a textual region of a Python program where a namespace is accessible*?

Answer (score 0):

A name space is always accessible by qualifying a reference. It is directly accessible if the reference does not need to be qualified.

Comment: "It is directly accessible if the reference does not need to be qualified." —  Let's say if a namespace `foo` is accessible indirectly. It means we can do `foo.spam` to access `spam` in the namespace `foo`. For that to work, we need to be able to look up `foo` first. In other words, the name `foo` should be directly accessible even in this case. Is there a case where a reference does not need to be qualified?

Comment: if `foo` is directly accessible, and `spam` is a reference in that namespace, then you can just refer to it as `spam`. This would presumably happen when you specifically import `spam` (e.g. `from foo import spam`) or you import the contents of the namespace (`from foo import *`), but not when you import the namespace itself (`import foo`)

Comment: But I am not able to understand why the term "directly accessible" needs to be defined?